# Emploi de « ceci étant démontré »

Tags: traduction, anglais, usage

> The different strain measures can be formally reduced to those of linear elastic systems, **this being demonstrated**.
>
> Les différentes mesures de déformation peuvent être formellement réduites à celles des systèmes élastiques linéaires, **ceci étant démontré**.

L'expression « *ceci étant démontré* » a-t-elle l'air bizarre en français ?

Faut-il la remplacer par :

> Les différentes mesures de déformation peuvent être formellement réduites à celles des systèmes élastiques linéaires, **ce qui est démontré**.

?

Comment: Il ne serait pas inutile de savoir ce qui suit la phrase, de savoir aussi si le procédé de réduction des mesure est un calcul mathématique ou une expérience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Ceci étant démontré* est plus indiqué pour débuter une nouvelle phrase.

Suivant ce que tu souhaites dire, tu peux le remplacer dans ta phrase par:

> Ce qui a été démontré.
>
> Ce que nous avons démontré.
>
> Ce que nous démontrons.
>
> Ce qui est démontré (ici).
>
> Ce que nous allons démontrer.